# Macro for appending suffix to unsigned long long literal

Tags: c++, macros

I am working with a library that defines a constant like this:

```
#define SOME_BIG_CONSTANT 0x0000000100000000
```

This literal is too large to be represented as `long`, so any program that uses this macro fails to compile (using gcc 4.1.2 for VxWorks). The (non-standard, but supported by this compiler) solution that works is to add the suffix `ull` to the literal:

```
#define SOME_BIG_CONSTANT 0x0000000100000000ull
```

However, that would require me to modify the library-header, which I'd rather not do. I suck at macros, so my question is, how can I define a macro that would add that suffix, which I could call like this:

```
ULL_(SOME_BIG_CONSTANT)
```

Which would expand to:

```
0x0000000100000000ull
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ull** is a standard suffix on C++11.

On the other hand, you may define the following macros:

```
#define APPEND(x, y) x ## y
#define ULL(x) APPEND(x, ull)
```

Now, you can use:

```
int main()
{ 
  unsigned long long a = ULL(SOME_BIG_CONSTANT);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `unsigned long long a`, when using the `ull` suffix?

Answer (score 4):

```
#define ULL_2(NUM) NUM ## ull
#define ULL_(NUM) ULL_2(NUM)
```

Should do the job. (Note: untested)

The second macro is needed to trigger macro expansion on the passed macro.